# Dynamic plot with button and slider

Tags: plotting

How can I create a dynamic, interactive graph in Mathematica with buttons and sliders for changing the equation type and variables?

Comment: You can do it by reading documentation, which is excellent.

Comment: have you seen Manipulate? There are over 12,000 examples at https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/

Comment: I forgot my manners. A proper welcome with some useful links hopefully

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica S.E. To start: 1) take the [introductory tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), since the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) consider accepting the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 5):

```
g = 1;
dm = DynamicModule[{a}, 
   Column[{Dynamic@
      Plot[Sin[(a + g) x], {x, 0, Pi}, PlotRange -> {All, {-1, 1}}], 
     Slider[Dynamic@a, {0, 4}]}]];
Button["g++", g = g + 1]
Dynamic[dm]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

**Edit:** many thanks to @Nasser for the comment. Indeed, `Manipulate` might be more straightforward. It works like this:

```
g = 1;
Manipulate[
 Plot[Sin[(a + g) x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotLabel -> Row[{"a=", a}]], {a, 
  0, 5}]
Button["g++", g = g + 1]
```

Comment: nice example but I find Manipulate much simpler myself.

Comment: @Nasser thanks for pointing this out. I have adopted your comment in the edit :-)